# issue working with indexes on a table

Tags: mysql

Why does mysql does not use index when searching for empty string on an indexed column?

```
explain select * from DEFAULT_TABLE where RANDOMID = '';

| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | DEFAULT_TABLE | ALL  | RANDOMID      | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  108 | Using where |


explain select * from DEFAULT_TABLE where RANDOMID IS NULL;

| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | DEFAULT_TABLE | ref  | RANDOMID      | RANDOMID  | 9       | const |    1 | Using index condition |
```

Comment: which type is RANDOMID?

Comment: Field            Type     Null         Key   Default     Extra
RANDOMID bigint(20) unsigned YES         MUL  NULL

Comment: A bigint is a number. If you compare it to a string (`''`), MySQL tries to autocast it to fit. Comparing the values as a string makes it impossible to use the bigint index (that is ordered as numbers, not as strings: a string "123456" is lexigraphically ordered before the string "2", while the number 123456 is ordered after 2) to lookup the value. It actually makes no sense to compare a number (that is either null or, well, a number) to an empty string (which is not the same as being null), so check what you are actually looking for in that query (it is not equivalent to the second query!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274272/why-is-using-an-int-to-select-a-varchar-index-containing-numbers-much-slower-tha).

As @Solarflare wrote as comment, when an indexed field is compared to a different type parameter, MySQL doesn't use the index on that field because the strings order is different from the numbers order and for many others issues and differences related to the dictionary collation.

Overall different types have different 'rules' and should not be convenient to use index.